# Автоматическое уведомление на jquery и php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Хочу узнать технологию как реализовать такую идею как на stackoverflow.

Меня интересует как работает уведомление сообщений, т.е. человек сидит не обновляет страницу, ничего не делает, а ему в какой то момент показывает уведомдение об ответе на его вопрос. Как я думаю это работает.

1) оставляем вопрос , запись в БД.
2) у клиента запускается скрипт который допустим каждые 30 секунд проверяет есть ли ответ на вопрос, 
3) если есть ответ через jquery выводим уведомление вверху

Просто если каждые 30 секунд у всех пользователей обновлять, то наверно сервер нагнется, как ребят реализована эта идея?

В Андройде есть такое понятие broadcast reciever. Эта служба которая ожидает ответа, и в случае получения ответа выполняет какое либо действие.

Comment: Смотри в сторону сокетов https://learn.javascript.ru/websockets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если обладаете минимальными знаниями английского языка, могу порекомендовать [данную статью](https://pusher.com/tutorials/realtime-notifications#/lang=php).

Это упрощенный вариант реализации через сервис pusher.com с использованием готовых библиотек.

Для реализации собственной системы уведомлений вам потребуется держать  вебсокет "демона". За вас никто подобную систему писать не будет, возникнут вопросы, обращайтесь